# RegExp - {} not {{

Tags: regex, replace

I'm searching for a RegExp that finds {}

I was under the understanding that this: 
/[{}]{2}/g;

- regexpression finds:
  {} and only the brackets if they stand exactly like that next to each other. I'm doing some code that makes me believe that I misunderstood that.

I now have this line:
{{x,y},{0.0,1.0},{0.2,1.2214},{0.4,1.49182},{0.6,1.82212},{0.8,2.22554},{1.0,2.71828}}

And it becomes:
{ }x,y},{0.0,1.0},{0.2,1.2214},{0.4,1.49182},{0.6,1.82212},{0.8,2.22554},{1.0,2.71828{ }

That wasn't what I wanted, the above line should not be influenced by my regexp, because nowhere there is a "{}".

+++

ok so i misunderstood, How to do a rexeprexstion that ONLY findes "{}" when they stand exactly like that, no space between them, } comes after { ???

Comment: `[{}]{2}` is the same as `[{}][{}]` - two occurences of either brace. You're looking for `\{\}`.

Comment: `[{}]` is a character class - either of the two elements will match. Depending on your regex flavour, you can do `{}` or `\{\}` or even `[{][}]`

Comment: Only `{` needs escaping. `/\{}/`. But it ix more logical to use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you look for is just `\{\}`

(which is written `/\{\}/g` as a JavaScript Regex literal with *global* flag).

You needed to escape the `{` and `}`, not to use a character set.

`[{}]` means either `{` or `}`.

Comment: what are the leading backslash and the two slashes for?

Comment: @jhnc I guessed from OP's attempt he was using JavaScript

Comment: cheers, that explains slashes. my javascript is minimal. was the backslash a typo?

Comment: @jhnc Oh sorry, I had to look at the edit history to understand your comment. Yes it was a typo... It's easy to lose the count when you add slashes and backslashes...

Comment: Hi, yeah I'm working in actionscript3

Comment: So I don't need the {2} ?

Comment: @SamiAl-beik No you don't need it if you want just one occurrence of {}

Comment: ok thanks, I will implement this solution